# XSS in ActionScript navigateToURL

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, xss

We have

```
navigateToURL((new URLRequest(urlToLoad)), "_self");
```

in ActionScript. *urlToLoad* is received from param.

```
urlToLoad = loaderInfo.parameters[param]
```

So if someone would call our swf with

```
param=javascript:alert(document.domain)
```

it would show classic XSS technique in AS. Unfortunatelly, we also use that. I know that we should remove such mechanism, but it will have to wait until we switch to html5. I did search for solution all over the Internet (Google & Bing), but couldn't find acceptable solution.

Is there some way to white list only several of our own functions?